# Type error: `list' expected, found `initialstate(_G2903,list,_G2905)' can't solve it at prolog

Tags: prolog

In prolog I got this error

> Type error: 'list' expected, found `initialstate(_G2903,list,_G2905)'

I have a initial state which is

```
initialstate(0, [], [[1,0],[2,3],[1,2],[1,3]]).
```

and I want the lenght of the first list to be empty so I wrote

```
?- length(initialstate(_,list,_), X).
```

Prolog throws up the error above. The right result must be

```
X=0
```

Am I doing wrong? how I could fix it? I am new in prolog programming. Sorry if it is stupid mistake.

Comment: Most basic things are wrong. That is, the syntax: you cannot start a functor/predicate with an                                         unquoted uppercase. Try simple fact-based examples first.

Comment: You have right, sorry, i correct it but it throws up another error....

Comment: should be `?- initialstate(_,List,_), length(List, X).`

Comment: In Prolog you have to remember that identifiers starting with lower case are atoms, starting with upper case are uninstantiated variables, and predicates are *not* functions that return values like in C.